# Share data between iOS-app and Apple Watch companion app?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, data-sharing

I only find old threads about this topic. Apples documentation is really hard to understand. So I have an iOS-app with a widget that's fetching data once a day and then display the info as a widget on the iPhone.

Now I want to add an Apple Watch companion app (with a "watch face"-widget too). I have added an Apple Watch app as a target to my project. Now I'm trying to use an App Group-container to sync data between the apps. That is obviously not working.

I have read a little about the WatchConnectivity-framework, but that seems to be the wrong choice too. According to Apples documentation, WatchConnectivity should only be used as an additional method of syncing data between an iPhone and an Apple Watch, and shouldn't be 100% relied on (if I understand the documentation correctly).

It seems like a bad idea to make network calls to an API both from both the iPhone and the watch - when it's exactly the same data.

What's the best way to "mirror" data available on the iPhone to the Apple Watch in 2023? And what about an Apple Watch Widget with a timeline? Can I get a timeline from the iPhone instead of making network calls from the Apple Watch widget?